# How to remove and add relationships in single neo4j query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need some advice in order to adding and removing relationship on the same node during the same query (the same cypher script).

Let's say we have a `:User`, who have several relationships with node `:Page`.
I wanna add missing relationship from the array `['toto', 'titi', 'tete']` and i would also like to remove relationship already present in the db but not present in the array.

```
MATCH (u:User {username: "carere"}), (pages:Page) WHERE pages.title IN ['toto', 'titi', 'tete']
WITH u, pages
MERGE (u)-[:WROTE]->(pages)
WITH u, pages
MATCH (u)-[r:WROTE]->(p) WHERE NOT p.title IN ['toto', 'titi', 'tete']
DELETE r
RETURN u, r, pages
```

The query is working, but i would like to know if i should separate this statement in 2 queries or if i keep with my single query, anyway which is the best solution to achieve what im trying to do ?

Thx a lot for your time, have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep everything you need in one query as far as it gives you desired result. The best way how to operate with your data depends on schema and amount of data in your database. Take a look at [Query tuning](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/), which includes execution plan and profiling.

For example, on minimal dataset after profiling your query I got a summary

```
Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 76 total db hits in 11 ms.
```

On the same dataset I've try modified query

```sql
profile 
MATCH (u:User {username: "carere"})-[r:WROTE]->(:Page) DELETE r
WITH u MATCH (pages:Page) WHERE pages.title IN ['toto', 'titi', 'tete']
MERGE (u)-[r:WROTE]->(pages)
RETURN u, r, pages
```

with summary

```
Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 70 total db hits in 9 ms.
```

But if we'll extend our dataset with additional independent nodes with query

```sql
UNWIND range(0, 100) as entityId
CREATE (: User {username: "user" + entityId})-[:WROTE]->(: Page {title: "title" + entityId})
```

then profiling summary will be looking a bit different

```
# first query
Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 1562 total db hits in 52 ms.

#modified query
Cypher version: CYPHER 3.5, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 676 total db hits in 19 ms.
```

And with that you information can start playing with [indexes and schema tuning](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/schema/)

Hope it could be useful.

Comment: Superb explanation @Dmytro Patserkovskyi :D i really liked and understood your explanation, i know how to profile the cost of my queries, thanks to you :) I mark this one as resolve, have a great day :)

Comment: @Carere I'm happy to help, have a great day too :)